# emacs menu options while running in terminal

Tags: emacs

When running emacs in terminal mode (usually over a remote login) I can see the usual pulldown menus (file, edit, options etc) at the top of the screen, but I have no idea how to operate them.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the function key <kbd>f10</kbd> (`menu-bar-open`) to open the menu.

Comment: `M-\`` is the binding I'm used to for this. That's bound to `tmm-menubar` which isn't an alias of `menu-bar-open`, but the two do seem to behave identically. (Ah, I see -- `menu-bar-open` activates the GUI menus on X displays, and uses `tmm-menubar` as a fall-back.)

Answer (score 0):

One way , install [LaCarte](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte) and call `lacarte-execute-menu-command`